# Is there a way on Serializer perform create to save a field which is a Foreign Key

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have two models **Timesheet** and **Employee** now on my use case I want to save automatically the **employee** field of the timesheet using the **perform_create** but the api returns an error of **"ValueError at /api/timesheet_entry/\nCannot assign \", , ]>\": \"Timesheet.employee\" must be a \"Employee\" instance.**

What I was trying to do is save the Timesheet's **employee** field to the Employee's **login** field using the **id**.

below are the information on the models, serializer and the viewsets.

```
class Timesheet(models.Model):
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="Start Date", null=True, blank=True, default=None, editable=True, help_text="", unique=False, db_index=False,)
    end_date = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="End Date", null=True, blank=True, default=None, editable=True, help_text="", unique=False, db_index=False,)
    employee = models.ForeignKey('Employee', on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="timesheet_entry_employee",
        verbose_name="Employee", null=True, blank=True, editable=True, unique=False)
    comment = models.CharField(verbose_name="Comment", null=True, blank=True, default=None, editable=True, max_length=255,)
    total_hours = models.DecimalField(verbose_name="Total Hours", null=True, blank=True, default=0.00, max_digits=19, decimal_places=2,)
```

and

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name="Name", max_length=255,)
    login = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="employee_login",
        verbose_name="Login", editable=True)
    hourly_cost = models.DecimalField(verbose_name="Hourly Cost", null=False, blank=False, editable=True, max_digits=19, decimal_places=2,)
    charge_out_rate = models.DecimalField(verbose_name="Charge Out Rate", null=False, blank=False, max_digits=19, decimal_places=2,)
```

and in the serializer

```
class TimesheetEntrySerializer(WritableNestedModelSerializer):
    employee = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=False, read_only=False, allow_null=True, queryset=models.Employee.objects.all())
```

viewset's perform create

```
def perform_create(self, serializer):
        user_id = self.request.user
        employee_user = models.Employee.objects.get(employee__login=user_id)
        return serializer.save(employee=employee_user)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Employee.objects.filter(...)` returns a QuerySet, which is a list of `Employees`. Because your query is specific enough the list will only contain one element, [but it will still be a list.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-a-single-object-with-get)

Also, you should just use login__id, since you're already querying on employee. The proper way to retrieve a single object is to use `Employee.objects.get(login__id = request)` instead.

Note that when `.get()` cannot find an object, it will raise a `DoesNotExist` exception.

---

Another way to retrieve the current employee would be to use the `related_name` on employee from the user object:

```
employee = self.request.user.employee_login
```

---

A few unrelated things I noticed about your code:

- You use `login` to refer to the user, and a related name `"employee_login"` to refer back to the employee. It's better to just call them what they are, `user` and `'employee'`.
- You get `self.request.user.id` and store it in a variable called `request`. While this does not cause issues per se, it might be better to chose a more unique verbose name, like `user_id` for instance.
- You get the user id using `self.request.user.id` and then query for the employee using `login__id`. You can also simply retrieve the user with `self.request.user`, and then query for that user using `login = user`.

---

EDIT:

I see you are using

```
employee_user = models.TimesheetEntry.objects.get(employee__login=user_id)
```

This doesn't make sense, you want to retrieve the current user's employee object, right here, you are trying to get a TimesheetEntry.

```
user_id = self.request.user
employee_user = models.Employee.objects.get(login=user_id)
```

Now I'm not sure if you can simply pass an object instance to a PrimaryKeyRelatedField, so either use

```
return serializer.save(employee=employee_user)
```

or

```
return serializer.save(employee=employee_user.id)
```

EDIT 2:

You can bypass the serializer altogether by doing the following:

```
def perform_create(self, serializer):
        user_id = self.request.user
        employee_user = models.Employee.objects.get(employee__login=user_id)
        timesheet_entry = serializer.save()
        timesheet_entry.employee = employee_user
        timesheet_entry.save()
        return timesheet_entry
```

Comment: I have edited my answer. You need to make sure you are passing an `Employee` object, or the id of an `Employee` object to your serializer.

Comment: sorry I've updated the question again, yeah it doesn't make sense if I want to retrieve the current user's employee object in that way, been coding and figuring this one out the whole day, again sorry. I've followed your code and the api returns an error of **Got a `TypeError` when calling `TimesheetEntry.objects.create()`. This may be because you have a writable field on the serializer class that is not a valid argument to `TimesheetEntry.objects.create()`. You may need to make the field read-only, or override the TimesheetEntrySerializer.create() method to handle this correctly.**.

Comment: Interesting, I'm not aware of this error. Let me investigate for a bit. In the meantime, I've edited my answer (again), with a way to save your TimeSheetEntry without using the serializer for adding the employee.

Comment: Do you have an example of data that you pass to the viewset?

Comment: class TimesheetEntryViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = TimesheetEntrySerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend)
    ordering_fields = ('start_date','end_date','employee'','comment','total_hours',)
    search_fields = ('start_date','end_date','employee','comment','total_hours',)

Comment: hi I've solved my issue thanks to you. I've played a little bit in the code and got what I needed.